# Get the lat/lon of a destination, which should be autocompleted

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm completely newb at Ionic2/Angular2 but currently developing a little App. I would need to get the lat/lon of a destination, which should be autocompleted. I'm using the Google Maps Autocomplete for that so I thought I could use it on the App too! Currently I'm trying following directive:

https://github.com/rajan-g/angular2-google-place-autocomplete

My Code is like:

ort_hilfe.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {GoogleplaceDirective} from './directives/googleplace.directive';

@Component({
   selector : 'searchbox',
   directives: [GoogleplaceDirective],
   template:  `
       <input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "address"  (setAddress) = "getAddress($event)" googleplace/>
       `    
})
export class AppComponent {
   public address : Object;
   getAddress(place:Object) {       
       this.address = place['formatted_address'];
       var location = place['geometry']['location'];
       var lat =  location.lat();
       var lng = location.lng();
       console.log("Address Object", place);
   }
}
```

ort.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import {SuchService} from '../SuchService';

@Component({
templateUrl: 'build/pages/suche/ort/ort.html',
})
export class Ort {

constructor(private navController: NavController,private suchService: SuchService) {


}

ortSelected(item) {this.suchService.setimmoOrt(item.title, item.lat, item.lon);this.navController.pop(); }

orte = [
  {
    'title': 'Saarlouis',
    'lat': 4.43,
    'lon': 4.5,
  },
];
}
```

ort.html

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
<ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of orte" (click)="ortSelected(item)">
{{item.title}}
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I would like to use the autocomplete Field, which should fade in over the classic list + a defined List of common places:

[image]

Comment: Ops I see. Did you see any error in Chrome Developer console?

Comment: nope :( Just nothing